# open all files inside list of list in python at once

Tags: python, for-loop

I am using a code below to open file from list of list one by one

```
name = [['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory'],['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team'],['jimmy', 'rob', 'stack', 'layla', 'london']]

for i in name:
    for k in i:
        a = open(f'{k}.txt')
```

would like to know if it is possible to one set of list files at the same time like for
['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory']. want to open this file then next list files.

Comment: may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550290/how-to-open-a-list-of-files-in-python

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python

Comment: The code already does that, doesn't it? The inner `for` opens the list of files then returns back to the outer `for` which will move to the next list.

Comment: no i want to last loop to open all files at the same time like:  a = open('tina.txt'), b = open('vans.txt'), c = open('john.txt'), d = open('sam.txt'),e = open('victory.txt') all at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, you cannot open multiple files in the same variable at once.

It would be best to use the file to do what you would want to do, e.g storing the text on the file in a list, then going to the next one and doing the same. It's quite hard to give you a workaround if you don't say what you mean to do with the files

Here is what I would do:

```
name = [['tina', 'vans', 'john', 'sam', 'victory'],['nanny', 'pink', 'sidewalk', 'paper', 'team'],['jimmy', 'rob', 'stack', 'layla', 'london']]

a = open(f'{name[0][0]}.txt') #for one time use

def get_name(index1, index2): #for use wherever
    a = open(f'{name[index1][index1]}.txt')
    return a

currentName = get_name(0,0) #returns tina.txt file
```

Comment: so main reason is to overlay multiple layers of images thats why i need to open all files at once.

Comment: is it possible to put value of k to next file on every loop.

Comment: Multiple layers of images? why is it in a text file then?

Comment: > is it possible to put value of k to next file on every loop.
no, unfortunately. I'm not quite sure why you would though

Comment: i have give it as just an example.

Comment: can you give me code snippet as i am having hard time figuring it out. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235235/discussion-between-zac-and-eden-gibson).